# How would I alter this integer item to concatenate into a list correctly? (Python)

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a new multidimensional list, with each item consisting of a list of words taken from a list of taggedDocuments, and an integer representing a label.

The issue I am having is that attempting to append both the list of words and the integer value for the label to the new list returns:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

My code is as follows:

```
labelled_docs = []

def DocLabel(docs,labels):
    i = 0
    while i < len(docs):
        templist = []
        templist.append(docs[i])
        labelled_docs.append(templist + labels[i])
        del templist [:]
        i += 1

listed_docs = list(documents)

listed_labels = clusterer.labels_.tolist()

DocLabel(listed_docs,listed_labels)
```

I'm struggling to work out how I need to change the listed_labels item in order to allow the lists to concatenate correctly. I've done some research into the problem, however I can't seem to find anything pertaining to the particular issue i'm having.

Comment: can you post any sample data and o/p ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert `labelled_docs.append(templist + labels[i])` this line into 
`labelled_docs.append(templist + [labels[i]])`.

This will concatenate two list instead of concatenation of one `list` and one `int` value.